# Popover for UIButton inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector

How can I fix this error?

> Use of unresolved identifier 'popover'

```
    @IBAction func btnSelectClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let popController = PopoverController(items: setupPopItem(), fromView: acceptButton, direction: .up, reverseHorizontalCoordinates: true, style: PopoverStyle.normal, initialIndex: 1) {
            print("Yeah Done !!")
        }
       popover(popController) //Im getting an error on this line
    }

    private func setupPopItem() -> [PopoverItem]{
        let google = PopoverItem(title: "Google", titleColor: .clear, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "a1")) {
            debugPrint($0.title) 
        }
        return [google]
    }
```

Comment: Share more info about your controller. Popover  must be function or something. I don't think anyone can help you with the current info